# Lagrangian Mechanics - Is the Given Answer Incorrect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

> A heavy symmetric top rotating about a fixed point has Lagrangian
> $$L=\frac{I_1}{2}(\dot \theta ^2 + \dot \phi^2 \sin ^2 \theta)+\frac{I_3}{2}(\dot \psi + \dot \phi \cos \theta)^2-mgl\cos \theta$$
> where $I_1=I_2, I_3$ are its principal moments of inertia and ($\phi, \theta, \psi$) are the Euler angles.
> [image]

> Write down the two conserved generalised momenta, $p_\phi$ and $p_\psi$, and show that $\theta$ obeys the equation $$I_1 \ddot \theta = -\frac{\partial V_{eff}}{\partial \theta}$$
> where
> $$V_{eff}(\theta) = \frac{(p_\phi - p_\psi \cos \theta)^2}{2I_1 \sin ^2 \theta} + mgl \cos \theta$$

Using $p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i}$ we can easily find that:
$$p_\phi = I_1\dot \phi \sin ^2 \theta + I_3 \cos \theta (\dot \psi + \dot \phi \cos \theta)$$
$$p_\psi = I_3 (\dot \psi + \dot \phi \cos \theta)$$
Now, using the Euler-Lagrange equation on the $\theta$ co-ordinate:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}$$
$$\rightarrow I_1 \ddot \theta = I_1 \dot \phi^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta - I_3 \dot \phi \sin \theta (\dot \psi + \dot \phi \cos \theta) + mgl\sin \theta \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

Now we just need to show that this right-hand side equals $-\frac{\partial V_{eff}}{\partial \theta}$. Note that:

$$p_\phi - p_\psi \cos \theta = I_1 \dot \phi \sin ^2 \theta$$
therefore
$$V_{eff} = \frac{I_1^2 \dot \phi^2 \sin^4 \theta}{2I_1 \sin ^2 \theta} +mgl\cos \theta = \frac{I_1}{2} \dot \phi ^2 \sin ^2 \theta + mgl\cos \theta$$
and so
$$ -\frac{\partial V_{eff}}{\partial \theta} = I_1 \dot \phi ^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta +mgl \sin \theta $$

and so the given answer dramatically fails to reproduce the term containing $I_3$ and $\dot \psi$ which shows up in the Euler-Lagrange equation ($*$).

Have I misunderstood something? The question seems to be incorrect!

Comment: "Check my work" type questions are almost always considered off-topic of this site and will likely be closed. See, for example: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot{\phi}$ is not a constant of the motion, so you can't treat it as constant when taking the derivative of $V_\text{eff}$ with respect to $\theta$.  If you leave $V_\text{eff}$ in its original form, calculate $\partial V_\text{eff}/\partial \theta$ in terms of $p_\phi$ and $p_\psi$, and *then* replace those quantities with their definitions in terms of the velocities, you will get the correct result.